# Getting and setting multiple items from a Sharepoint list using CAML query?

Tags: list, javascript, caml-query, caml

I have a SharePoint list `Catalog`.

Using `camlQuery` I can get a list item value called `Price`.

With the following code I get the `Price` value of the list element which has the `ID` 5 and store it in a variable `price_id5`.

```
var itemprices = {};

// Gets values from Catalogue list; but they can't be used in the Position list because of different formats
function retrieveListItems() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    catalogueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Catalog');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); // initiate the query object
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Values><Value Type=\'Number\'>5</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>6</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>7</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>');
    itemColl = catalogueList.getItems(camlQuery);

    // returns the item collection based on the query
    context.load(itemColl);
    context.executeQueryAsync(retrieveListItemsSuccess, retrieveListItemsFail);
}

function retrieveListItemsSuccess() {
    var listItemEnumerator = itemColl.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        itemprices[oListItem.id] = oListItem.get_item('Preis');
        console.log("itemprices 5: " + itemprices[5]);
        console.log("Price of list item at is:" + itemprices[oListItem.id]);
    }
}
// This function is executed if the above call fails
function retrieveListItemsFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get list items. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

How can I efficiently get the `Price` value of other list elements and store them in variables like `price_id6`, `price_id7` etc.?

I want to store them in variables in order to set these values in another list, but I don't know how without writing the three functions for every single price..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a general JavaScript question than SharePoint-specific, but the easiest way is just to use an array variable: `var itemprices = [];` and then push the values as you find them `itemprices.push(oListItem.get_item('Price'));`, and then you can loop through your array when you want to do something with each Price.

Alternatively, you could use a Javascript object, using the IDs as the Key,
so `var itemprices = {};`, then save each value like `itemprices[currentId] = oListItem.get_item('Price');`

However, looking at your code though, if you have multiple IDs, you put them all in a single caml using the `<In>` element, for example:

`<View><Query><Where><In><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/><Values><Value Type=\'Number\'>5</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>6</Value><Value Type=\'Number\'>7</Value></Values></In></Where></Query></View>`

and then that way, in your `retrieveListItemsSuccess` function, your `listItemEnumerator.moveNext()` will actually loop through all 3 items (or however many ID's are in your query).

Comment: Thank you, but I get undefined values for the itemprices. I edited the code in the post real quick to show you what I changed it to. Do you by any change know what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to change `Price` to `Preis`?  If the field name is spelled incorrectly, that would be a problem.

Comment: Yes that was intentional. I just changed it to english before, because "Preis" is german

Comment: ah, you are likely getting valid values, but your incrementer `i++` is in the wrong place -- you increment `i` before you call `console.log` so that value doesn't exist in the object.

Comment: You have good eyesight!! Now it works. Made my day, thanks a lot for your help man

Comment: btw, you kind of merged the two techniques -- if you are going to use an incrementer, it would be better to define `itemprices` as an array and `.push` each value as you receive it.  Or, if you keep `itemprices` defined as an object, then instead of using an incrementer, set the object value as `itemprices[oListItem.id] = oListItem.get_item('Preis');` that way your key is also the sharepoint item ID.

Comment: Give me a second I'll try that out

Comment: It works, but what exactly is that `oListItem.id`? How can I print out a specific itemprice?

Comment: the `.id` property of the list item is SharePoint's numeric ID of that list item.  So, in your code example, your query is retrieving items #5, #6, and #7, so then when you loop through the results, the first iteration `oListItem.id` will be equal to 5, and the second one will be equal to 6, and so on.  So then later you could use your object `itemprices[6]` to get the price of item #6.

Comment: Makes sense, but when I use `console.log("itemprices 5: " + itemprices[5]);` it tells me that it's undefined. I edited the code in the post to show you what I have

Comment: try removing the `console.log("itemprices 5: " + itemprices[5]);` line and replacing it with `console.log("retrieved price for itemid: " + oListItem.id);`, it is entirely possible that the three items are not coming back in numerical order.

Comment: It's weird, but `oListItem.id` is undefined itself

Comment: Do a console.log(oListItem) and console.log(itemprices).  This should let us see all the properties on those two objects.